# go to anchor link if url equals to

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to use a jquery on load function and I want it to scroll down to the anchor if the url is, for example:

url = http://test.aspx?section=section2

How can I achieve this through jquery? (I don't want to use anchor links because I'm using asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it with jQuery, you need the following code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript). It is to get querystring parameters from the url. Then if you have the correct parameter you can scroll to it's position.

```
<div style="height: 10000px">Large spacer</div>
<div id="section2">Scrolled to here!</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var offset = $('#' + getParameterByName('section')).offset().top;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: offset
        }, 1000);
    });


    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
        var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }
</script>
```